# Setting a variable inside a conditional

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to set a variable from the output of a command inside of a conditional where the conditional is false if nothing gets assigned to the variable.

If I set the variable to a grep with no return and then test:

```
test=$(echo hello | grep 'helo')
if [[ ! -z $test ]]; then
  echo "is set"
else
  echo "not set"
fi
```

Output: not set (this is expected)

But I'm trying to put it all into one statement like this:

```
test=
if [[ ! -z test=$(echo hello | grep 'helo') ]]; then
  echo "is set"
else
  echo "not set"
fi
```

output: "is set" (expected not set)

Comment: `test=` is the same as `test=""`, so the variable is not unset, but set to the empty string.

Comment: @Socowi, ...the variable isn't being set *at all*; the string `test=` is being compared against the empty string, not evaluated as an assignment.

Comment: @ArchieArchbold : In your second example, the variable `test` doesn't get assigned inside the `if` statement. Instead, `-z` looks at the string *test=SOMETHING*, and this string is always non-empty, because no matter what *SOMETHING* evaluates to, the argument of the `-z` operator always starts with *test=*. Side note: If you replace `! -z` by `-n`, the code gets a bit more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` returns success if there is a match, so you can just do:

```
if test=$(echo hello | grep 'helo')
then
  echo "Match: $test"
else
  echo "No match"
fi
```

If you're running something that doesn't differentiate by exit code, you can assign and check in two statements on the same line:

```
if var=$(cat) && [[ -n $var ]] 
then
  echo "You successfully piped in some data."
else
  echo "Error or eof without data on stdin."
fi
```

(or `;` instead of `&&` if you want to inspect the result even when the command reports failure)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack, using the shell's [parameter expansion alternate value](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) syntax, `echo -e` and some backspaces:

```
test=$(echo hello | grep 'helo'); echo -e not${test:+\\b\\b\\bis} set
```

Which outputs `is set` or `not set` depending on what `grep` finds.